# Radeon HD 6750 running at 120 Mhash/s table shows 167Mhash/s

Tags: miner-configuration, gpu-mining

I'm using guiminer with flags -v -f30 -w128 under windows 7 but all i get is 120Mhash/s thats like 75% of what the table shows. Any idea why is that?

Comment: People, please add a comment when downvoting.

Comment: What's your GPU temp?

Comment: 34C ..............

Comment: 54C under load,

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ATI Drivers 11.12 or 12.0 or above you need to set the worksize to 64.

Also the new drivers are a bit slower then pre 11.12 drivers.

Comment: Setting the worksize to 64 didn't help ;/ any other ideas why is this happening?